# Does the Heartbeat Openssl Bug also affect Servers who enforce Client Authentication?

Tags: openssl, heartbleed

Regarding the priority to upgrade servers, I want to confirm this, as I read in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6520 chapter 3:

> However, a HeartbeatRequest message SHOULD NOT be sent during
> handshakes.  If a handshake is initiated while a HeartbeatRequest is
> still in flight, the sending peer MUST stop the DTLS retransmission
> timer for it.  The receiving peer SHOULD discard the message
> silently, if it arrives during the handshake.  In case of DTLS,
> HeartbeatRequest messages from older epochs SHOULD be discarded.

Am I correct to think that, if a server only accepts SSL connections from known clients, no one else can exploit the bug during the handshake?

My understanding is that the message should be dropped and that the server does not answer.

Comment: Typically malware authors **DO NOT** care about the RFC. If the RFC says that the client should not request heartbeats during a handshake, this is just a nice hint to malware authors that there might be an exploit opportunity somewhere around here, by doing just that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the affected versions of OpenSSL don't implement that "SHOULD": they honour heartbeat messages during the handshake. Yeah, OpenSSL should discard such messages until the handshake has been completed -- but it should also *not* return data bytes outside of its buffer, and yet it does.

Therefore, no, requiring a complete handshake with client authentication does not protect against the bug.

Comment: Ok, maybe they should change SHOULD to MUST..

But thank you for your answer!

Comment: @MatthiasKnoll that's a matter of semantics. The protocol clearly required it not to for obvious security purposes, and someone did not double check that condition.